# Bridge CDI event to Microprofile Reactive Message broker

Tags: apache-kafka, quarkus, reactive-streams, microprofile

I followed the [Quarkus - Using Apache Kafka with Reactive Messaging](https://quarkus.io/guides/kafka) to create a sample to taste it, I changed message flow like this:

1. When a post is saved, fire an event by CDI.
2. Received the CDI and send to Kafka topic.
3. Read the data from Kafka topic, and expose it as SSE to the client.

The config for Kafka messaging, part of `application.properties`.

```
# Consume data from Kafka
mp.messaging.incoming.activities.connector=smallrye-kafka
mp.messaging.incoming.activities.value.deserializer=io.vertx.kafka.client.serialization.JsonObjectDeserializer

# Produce data to Kafka
mp.messaging.outgoing.activitiesOut.connector=smallrye-kafka
mp.messaging.outgoing.activitiesOut.topic=activities
mp.messaging.outgoing.activitiesOut.value.serializer=io.vertx.kafka.client.serialization.JsonObjectSerializer
```

The event handling class for CDI event and reactive messages.

```java
@ApplicationScoped
public class ActivityStreams {

    ReplaySubject<JsonObject> replaySubject;
    Flowable<JsonObject> flowable;

    @PostConstruct public void init() {
        replaySubject = ReplaySubject.create();
        flowable = replaySubject.share().toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER);
    }

    public void onActivityCreated(@ObservesAsync Activity activity) {
        replaySubject.onNext(JsonObject.mapFrom(activity));
    }

    @Outgoing("activitiesOut")
    public Publisher<JsonObject> onReceivedActivityCreated() {
        return flowable;
    }

    @Incoming("activities")
    @Outgoing("my-data-stream")
    @Broadcast
    public Activity onActivityReceived(JsonObject data) {
        Activity activity = data.mapTo(Activity.class);
        activity.setOccurred(LocalDateTime.now());
        return activity;
    }

}
```

When I tried to expose it as SSE, it does not work as expected.

```java
@Path("/activities")
@ApplicationScoped
public class ActivityResource {

    @Inject
    @Channel("my-data-stream")
    public Publisher<Activity> stream;

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.SERVER_SENT_EVENTS)
    @SseElementType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    Publisher<Activity> eventStream(){
        return stream;
    }
}
```

In the console logging, I saw the message sent to *activities* queue, but there is no further steps to SSE. And when I accessed the sse endpoint by `curl`, it always returned a *Not found* status.

```sh
curl -v -N  -H "Accept:text/event-stream" http://localhost:8080/activities  --connect-timeout 60

...
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```

The complete sample code is [here](https://github.com/hantsy/quarkus-sandbox/tree/master/rx-post-service).